# Facebook image sharing on wall of the user in unity3d using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I have implemented facebook login and sharing in unity3d for iOS and android. I am able to login and sharing image on the wall from my account. I am not able to post image on the wall of user from another facebook account. When i sharing image i am getting following response.
"{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException"}}".
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the Graph API page from Facebook Developer page.

Rdit the permissions.

Graph API needs permissions to publish data, maybe its for your own account only so please check that and try again.

So: go to tools and support,

- click graph api,
- select get access token,
- select the permissions you want.

After that in your code, when creating a request for image:

add the permission "publish_actions" ... something like

```
List<string> permissions = new List<string>();
permissions.Add("THE PERMISSION NAME");
```

Comment: Hi can you explain where is the permission option in the graph api page.

Comment: hi @user3249432 !  Say, you should really "Tick" this great answer.  I am giving it a bounty.